# C# WPF Button enabled if condition is met

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Im stuck on this assignment question:

> Create a new WPF Project with a TextBox that only accepts:
>
> US Zip Codes ##### or #####-#### Canadian Postal Codes: A#B#C# The
> window contains a Submit button that is only enabled when a valid zip
> code or postal code is entered.
>
> So for example, a user could enter 98122 or 98012-4444 or T1R2X4 and
> the Submit button would be enabled.
>
> The Submit button does not need to perform any action.
>
> Hint: Keep things simple and use a TextBox and an event on the
> TextBox.
>
> Hint: Don't use User Controls and don't use XAML binding. It's a lot
> of work.

This is what I have in the XAML  so far not sure if im supposed to be working in the cs file or XAML

```
<Window x:Class="ZipCode_TextBox.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ZipCode_TextBox"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="165" Width="471">
        <StackPanel>
    
            <TextBlock>Enter Zipcode:</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="zipCodeBox" />
           
            <Button x:Name="submitButton">Submit
            </Button>
    
        </StackPanel>
    </Window>
```

CS file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ZipCode_TextBox
{
    
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to ask your teacher about this. They obviously have some very specific implementation in mind, and only they can properly assist you with respect to your uncertainty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `TextChanged` event, you can use Regular Expressions to check the text box input to see if it matches your zip Code patterns of `#####`, `#####-####` and `A#B#C#`.  First add the event handler in XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="zipCodeBox" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

Handler code:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(zipCodeBox.Text))
    {
        if (Regex.Match(zipCodeBox.Text, "^\\d{5}(?:[-]\\d{4})?$").Success || //US Zips
            Regex.Match(zipCodeBox.Text, "^\\w{1}\\d{1}\\w{1}\\d{1}\\w{1}\\d{1}$").Success) //Canada Zips
        {
            submitButton.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            submitButton.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        submitButton.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Each time the text box's value changes, this will check to see if it matches the patterns you need, and enabled/disable the button.  Don't forget that you will want to default the button to disabled too.

```
<Button x:Name="submitButton" IsEnabled="False">Submit</Button>
```

Comment: Check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

There's a `TextChanged` event on the TextBox that will run your code every time the text changes. Use that to disable the button.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged

```
<TextBox TextChanged="textChangedEventHandler" />
```

```csharp
// TextChangedEventHandler delegate method.
private void textChangedEventHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    // Omitted Code: Insert code that does something whenever
    // the text changes...
} // end textChangedEventHandler
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-detect-when-text-in-a-textbox-has-changed

Comment: How would I check if the text is a zip code though?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you saying that binding is a lot of work?
I'd use a validating converter that accepts string and returns bool if the string is a valid US Zip Code or Canadian Postal Code (I've used Timothy's code for the validation):

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(bool))]
public class ZipCodeValidatingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(bool) && targetType != typeof(Object))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");

        Func<string, bool> ValidateZipCode = (c =>
             Regex.Match(c, "^\\d{5}(?:[-]\\d{4})?$").Success || // US Zips
             Regex.Match(c, "^\\w{1}\\d{1}\\w{1}\\d{1}\\w{1}\\d{1}$").Success); // Canada postal

        return ValidateZipCode(value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And then you bind the `IsEnabled` property of the "Submit" button to the content of your TextBox like this (you don't need to name the button unless it's required furhter in the code behind):

```
<Button Content="Submit" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=zipCodeBox, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource ZipCodeValidatingConverter}}" />
```

Of course, you need to add the resources section where you import the converter (if you include your converter in your local assembly):

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ZipCodeValidatingConverter x:Key="ZipCodeValidatingConverter" />
    <Window.Resources>
```

Again, I'm aware that this answer is against the hints you have given, I wanted to prove that using bindings is *not a lot of work* and once you master implementing and using the converters, you can benefit from it, e.g. you can automatically change the background of your text fields depending whether the content is valid or not. And that all without writing even a single line in your `.xaml.cs` file.

Comment: Yeah I personally didn't think they were alot of work either, was just trying to figure out how to do it according to instructions